# how to get parent object from child object in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    opportunity = models.ForeignKey(Opportunity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField()

class Opportunity(models.Model):
    ...some code
```

now I want to access offer from opportunity (child to parent). something like `opportunity.offer.status`. I have tried this but it doesn't work. Kindly help please, thanks.

Comment: You used a `ForeignKey`, hence this is a many-to-one relation. This thus means that for a (single) `Opportunity`, there can be zero, one, or *more* `Offer`s, so this is not child-to-parent, it is parent-to-child.

Comment: lets say i have one offer for one opportunity. then can you guide please?

Comment: That would be bad code design: you either should ensure there is only one opportunity, which is not the case here, or it is simply not something to do.

Comment: you should either thus redesign, or somehow come up with how you would treat the scenario if there are no offers, a single offer, or multiple offers. Preferrably these act as a *monoid*.

Answer (score 1):

> now i want to access `offer` from `opportunity` (child to parent). something like `opportunity.offer.status`. I have tried this but it doesn't work. Help please thanks.

It does not work, because this is not *child-to-parent*. Indeed, here `Offer` is the child, and `Opportunity` is the parent: a `ForeignKey` is a many-to-one relation, *not* a <s>one-to-many</s> relation: a single `Opportunity` can have zero, one or *many* related `Offer`s, an `Offer` has *exactly one* `Opportunity`, and an `Opportunity` does not per se has any `Offer`s, but it is also possible that there are multiple.

Since this can happen, you can not just "assume" that it is not the case, anything not restricted somehow (and preferrably by the database as well), *can* happen, and will eventually result in trouble if you don't take this into account.

You thus basically will have to "aggregate" somehow on the collection of `status`ses of the related `Offer`(s), that is often preferrably done in a way that can be defined as a [*monoid* structure <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). For example in databases, most aggregates like `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `COUNT` are all monoid structures.

You thus can for example use the *lexicographical* minimum of the statusses:

```
from django.db.models import Min

opportunity.offer_set.aggregate(result=Min('status'))['result']
```

or enumerate, for example with:

```
min([offer.status for offer in opportunity.offer_set.all()], default=None)
```

this will thus return `None` in case there is no related `Offer`, the status of the only offer if there is only one, and if there are two or more, the lixocographically smallest status.

I'm not saying that this is *the* one you need to pick, but just assuming there will be a sigle one is dangerous. This can be achieved with:

```
# bad idea

opportunity.offer_set.get().status
```

but will (likely) eventually fail when two ore more `Offer`s are linked to the same `Opportunity`, or we have an `Opportunity` where there is no `Offer` linked to it at all.

Answer (score 1):

actually you can access the offer model from the opportunity model by using the related name of the foreign key field and also set the related name of the fk field in the offer model to offer.

you can get better idea for this.

```
class offer(models.Models):
opportunity = models.foreignkey(opportunity, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='offers')
status = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
```

so then after can access all offers for an opportunity.

ex:-

```
opportunity = opportunity.object.get(id=1)
offers = opportunity.offers.all()
```